# Notification inbox ParseQueryAdapter NullPointer error

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have written a "Notification Inbox" tab for an application and initially had a hard coded channel to return to my listview. Every push notification that is sent will also be saved in a Notification table with the channels and message saved. Since not every user will be using the same channel I am trying to make the query compare the CurrentInstallation's channels(Installation table) with the Notification tables "channels" field.  The goal is to have a list item populate with the messages.

This is what I have

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> notificationAdapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity(), new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Notifications");
                    query.whereEqualTo("channels", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels"));
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    return query;
                }
            });
        notificationAdapter.setTextKey("msg");
        ListView notificationListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.notificationListView);

        notificationListView.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
```

the NullPointer error is coming from the

```
notificationListView.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
```

line.

I have one entry in Installation with channels "test".
I have 3 entries in Notifications with channels "test".

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Well you probably don't want to use equalTo for the channels constraint..  whereContainedIn is probably the winner, but you may have something else wrong considering the error you're getting.

Comment: whereContainedIn was a piece of the puzzle thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check if **notificationListView** is inside your **Rootview** of this Fragment or some of your values inside **notificationAdapter** is not present this 2 condition could cause **nullpointer** exception to this line.

Comment: rootView and whereContainedIn answered my question.  Thank you for your help.